# Donut Highcharts set different colors inner and outer data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts I have 3 department **Mechanical,Electrical,Communication**.In department have 3 works **new,process,completed** work.It has shown in Donut chart.I need set outside data color to fixed color(new,process,completed--red,green,yellow colors) and inner data color need to different that is except color only apply in inner data?

data.push({
            y: yValue,
            color: colors[i]});

I need mix up color color i.e is set color:colors[i]+colors[i+1] ?

Comment: Please add your code for better assist

Answer (score 0):

Refer this solution as per your requirement.

```
var innerColors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/abhash2610/9Lsessdy/1/)